# perturb or shock

Tags: synonyms

You must have been be perturbed when you saw your house roof was gone after you came back from holiday.

Can I substitute "perturbed" with "shocked" in this context? What other words I could use to express a shock like the one in the example?

Comment: have you consulted a thesaurus?

Answer (score 1):

Although perturbed and shocked mean similar things, there exists between them a difference of degree.

> Things that are shocking might stop you in your tracks, cause your mouth to gape open, or your eyes to bug out!  Things that are shocking don't happen very often.  They are *rare* occurrences which is one of the reasons they are shocking.  Things that are shocking are *extraordinary* things -- cars driving into crowds, hundreds of birds falling from the sky, or the roof blowing off of your house.
>
> Things that are perturbing might cause you to fidget, bite your fingernails, or just impede your sense of order.  Things that perturbing are *nagging* things -- children that won't clean their rooms, friends that stop by unannounced, etc.

Comment: +1   I was perturbed when I found my roommate's wet towels on the bathroom floor.  I was shocked when I found my roommate passed out on the bathroom floor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, There’s a world of difference between being shocked and being perturbed.
I'm sure you know "shocked" means feeling **surprised** ( and mostly **upset** ) by something very **unexpected** and **unpleasant** :

> We are all deeply **shocked** **(=surprised)** by what’s happened.
>   And look at this : 
>   He didn’t seem **perturbed** **by** the noises outside. OK, it simply means : He didn’t seem **worried** **about** the noises outside.

You definitely understand the difference between these two words.

Now let me give you some examples my friend :

> e.g. "Nick was **perturbed that** **(= worried about)** she didn’t look happy." 
>   e.g. "For a few minutes Nick stood in **shocked** **(= surprised and upset)** silence.

In a not-so-interesting comparison, we can say :
In written English, people often prefer to use perturbed rather than shocked, because it is more formal.